# What can cause AddFontMemResourceEx (gdi32.dll) to fail on some systems?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, gdi

I have some C# code running in a service that takes Windows Printer Spool files and renders them into images.  To do this, it has to load the embedded fonts.  This is deployed on numerous computers, and goes back 10+ years.  It has, as far as I know, worked without issue.

However, one Windows Server is now having problems with this, where `AddFontMemResourceEx()` is returning an invalid handle, and when the document is rendered, where the fonts should be is just garbled text.

I have retrieved the `.spl` file from the server in question, and when I render it on my own machine, the call to the API works without any issue.

This is not about what is in the spool file, it's something to do with that machine.

The documentation says that there is no further error information available if this goes wrong:

> If the function fails, the return value is zero. No extended error information is available.

Is there any information what might cause this function to fail on one server only, and/or how to diagnose the issue further?

The code is:

```cs
uint fonts;
handle = NativeMethods.AddFontMemResourceEx(bytes, (uint)bytes.Length, IntPtr.Zero, out fonts);

if (handle.IsInvalid)
```

Comment: `(uint)bytes.Length -10` seems rather arbitrary. Looks like code that may have worked by chance alone. What is that supposed to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry, that was some debugging code that I added to see the effects on the application if I made that call fail.  It is not the code that the real application runs, I've amended the post.  Thanks and further apologies.

Comment: A wild guess would be something like memory pressure in the non-paged memory pool -  perhaps that system has a buggy driver installed.